# Google Drive REST-API Internal error 500

Tags: multithreading, performance, google-drive-api, httprequest, internal-server-error

I'm developing an application that receives several massage queue containing 20-30 gmail addresses. My app owns a single google drive folder that must be shared with all of the users. My app uses Google drive Java client and for the HTTP calls I'm using [Google batching](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch)

The problem is that I'm getting internal error 500 when I'm trying to share the folder with 30 users simultaneously by multithreading. However when I use threads synchronisation everything is fine but the performance is terrible about 0.5 second per user!

Can anyone explain Why I'm receiving this error?

```
500 OK
        {
        "code" : 500,
        "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Internal Error. User message: \"An internal                                                     error has occurred which prevented the sharing of these item(s): fileame\"",
       "reason" : "internalError"
        } ],
      "message" : "Internal Error. User message: \"An internal error has occurred which prevented the sharing of these item(s): filename\""
        }
```

Here is the thread code:

```
try {
        //batch start
        BatchRequest batch = service.batch();
        ArrayList<String> users = readUsers(this.file);
        Permission[] permissions= new Permission[users.size()];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < users.size(); i++){
           permissions[i]= new Permission();
           permissions[i].setValue(users.get(i)+"@gmail.com");
           permissions[i].setType("user");
           permissions[i].setRole("writer");
           service.permissions().insert(fileId, permissions[i]).setSendNotificationEmails(Boolean.FALSE)                    .queue(batch, callback);                  
        }
        //batch execute
       batch.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred and I am " + id + ": " + e);
    }
```

Comment: 500 is normally flood protection you can only send so many requests a second.    Batching counts I have found that if you send 50 requests in a batch the server is not smart enough to keep it slow enough to avoid the 500 error.   sends smaller batches.

Comment: Im sending about 8 request per batch as Im using 4 threads.

Comment: I don't know any Google API that is going to like you sending threads.   However try https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/query-parameters  look at quotaUser send a different one for each thread and cross your fingers.

Comment: If that works I want to know! Btw 500 error you can normally implement exponential back off and send the same request again.  server will accept it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this? I have searched everywhere but I couldnt find any information on how to retry a failed request in a batch.

Comment: Here is the call back code:

Comment: JsonBatchCallback<Permission> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Permission>() {
      
            public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e,
                    HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
                    throws IOException {
                // Handle error
                System.err.println(e.getMessage()); }
       
            public void onSuccess(Permission permission,
                    HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
                    throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Permission ID: " + permission.getId());
            } };