# Setting file permissions in batch

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, async-await

I'm outputting the following error that's generated when executing a batch of file permission changes to a file. I'm not sure what to make of this, since it's only a problem for some of the files, and the issue doesn't trigger when trying to run in debug mode:

```
500 >> Internal Error. User message: "An internal error has occurred which prevented the sharing of these item(s): Example File.DOCX"
```

I'm using the following code:

```
var batch = new Google.Apis.Requests.BatchRequest(service);

Google.Apis.Requests.BatchRequest.OnResponse<Permission> callback = delegate (
            Permission permission,
            Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError error,
            int index,
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage message) {
                if (error != null) {
                    // Handle error
                    Console.WriteLine("File PERMISSION Error: " + error.Code + " >> " + error.Message);
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("File Permission ID: " + permission.Id);
                }
            };

Permission filePermission = new Permission()
{
    EmailAddress = "test-email@gmail.com"
    , Type = GoogleDriveRoleType
    , Role = GoogleDriveRole
};

var permExec = service.Permissions.Create(filePermission, googleDriveObjectId);
permExec.SendNotificationEmail = false;
permExec.Fields = "id";
batch.Queue(permExec, callback);

await batch.ExecuteAsync();
```

This code is within a method that's `public static async Task MyMethod(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to make your batch request smaller. You might be experiencing 500 internal error because you are flooding the server with too many request per second. As stated in this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967707/google-drive-rest-api-internal-error-500#comment63381488_37967707), as the server handles your batch request, it is not smart enough to slow down to avoid the error 500. You can also use exponential backoff and then retry the batch request. As stated in this [forum](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/444), currently there is no way to know in a batch request what part fail or succeed. You have to create your own implementation regarding this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mr Rebot. I was afraid that this would be the case. My batching is done for 2-3 permission updates per batch, and as you can see, it's executed once I have the batch ready. I've done similar batch updates on a folder level, and I didn't get this error as I'm seeing with file uploads. The method is basically the same there.